# How to prove $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})\cap(x,y) ≠\emptyset$ with $x,y∈\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have already proven that $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is an uncountable set. Doesn't that imply that for every interval $(x,y)$ there are numbers, thus $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is not empty?

Comment: What does “for every interval $(x,y)$ there are numbers” mean?

Comment: In other words: There is no intervall that does not encompass elements of $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\Bbb R\setminus(0,\infty)$ is uncountable, yet it has no elements in common with $(1,2)$. The number of elements is (more or less) irrelevant. It is their distribution which matters.

Comment: Hint. You don't wnat arguments about countability. You just have to show that any interval contains an irrational. What can you say about the rational multiples of $\pi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is not empty. But that doesn't by itself imply that the intersection with $(x,y)$ is not empty either.

The question can be rephrased as follows:

> if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, with $x<y$, then there exists an irrational number $r$ such that $x<r<y$.

Take a positive integer $q$ such that $q(y-x)>2$. Then there exists an integer $p$ such that $qx<p<qy$. Hence $x<p/q<y$ and we have proved that there is at least a rational number between $x$ and $y$. Therefore, we can find rational numbers $x'$ and $y'$ such that $x<x'<y'<y$.

Take a positive integer $n$ such that $n(y'-x')>\sqrt{2}$. Then
$$
x<x'<x'+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}<y'<y
$$
and the number $x'+\sqrt{2}/n$ is irrational.

Note that the only properties used are:

- every nonempty set of nonnegative integers has a least element
- if $0<a<b\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $ma>b$ (Archimedean property)
- the rational numbers are closed for addition, multiplication and division (by a nonzero divisor)
- $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Why does "then exist an integer $p$ sucht that $qx<p<qy$?"

Comment: @Analysis Because $qy-qx>2$. So the least integer greater than $qx$ is less than $qy$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: do you know that $(0,1) \cong \mathbb{R}$ (bijection)

If so you can prove that for $x \neq y$ you have $(x,y) \cong (0,1)$, and finish with $\mathbb{Q}$ being countable.